# sublime text (php / html / css / javascript)

Tags: php, html, css, sublimetext3

i am having a problem with SUBLIME TEXT , when i write the PHP code it is not working , its not giving[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSZVN.png) me any output

Comment: What do you mean with "is not working"?

Comment: Do you have any server installed on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have any local server **installed**

   **Windows:** [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) OR [WAMPP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

   **MAC**: [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/)
2. If server is installed then make sure it is **Running**.
3. Make sure you the **file extension** is `.php` NOT `.html`
4. Finally, you have to **access** it by opening browser and enter `localhost/PHPCodeDirectory` or `127.0.0.1/PHPCodeDirectory`

Hope it helps :)